# how to run a java class on android project?

Tags: java, android

i have writing an app with an android client and a server java. All the classes are in one package, but when i run my project i have this mistake:

```
guarantee(_name_index != 0 && _signature_index != 0) failed: bad constant pool index for fieldDescriptor
```

i read that it is because my server is written in java and not in android. so what can i do for test my code? i have create also a Java Project only for the server, but i don't know how import and link them.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? The error means only one thing - the classes are not correctly compiled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Java is a language, Android is the target you run it on.

Second,  run your program as `Android Application`.

`Run as > Android Application`

As long as you have one class that extends `Activity`, you are good to go.